# ¿Cómo puedo validar una llave foránea de mi formulario en tiempo real?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, sql-server

Quiero validar mi formulario en tiempo real, el registro de *id_orden*: que cuando escriba el número de orden, si no existe me salga un mensaje que diga que no existe la orden, y si sí existe se guarde el número de orden.

Adjunto mi vista y mi controlador.

Mi código lo estoy haciendo con Laravel.

```
<form action="{{ route('ordenes.recepciona_suc.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <br>

     <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin: 0 auto;">
        <label for="orden">No. Orden:</label>
        <input type="text" name="orden_id" id="orden_id" maxlength="6" class="form-control" required>
     </div>

        
        <p style="text-align:center;"><strong> Documentación Recibida</strong></p>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin: 0 auto;">
            <label for="INE">INE:</label>
            <input type="file" id="INE" name="INE" accept="image/*" class="mb-3 form-control">

        <br>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin: 0 auto">
            <label for="orden">Persona que recibió:</label>
            <input value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}" readonly class="form-control">
        </div>

        <br>

        <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center;">
            <button type="submit" value="Registrar" class="btn btn-primary"> Registrar </button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Este es mi controlador, mi método *store*:

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{

    $data = $request->validate([
        'orden_id' => 'required|string|exists:ordenes,orden',
        'FechaIngTaller' => 'required|date',
        'INE' => 'nullable|file',
        'Copiafact' => 'nullable|file',
        'poliza' => 'nullable|file',
        'observaciones' => 'nullable|string',
    ],
    [
        'orden_id.exists' => 'El ID de orden proporcionado no existe en la tabla "ordenes".',
    ]);

    $user = Auth::user();

    try {
        $orden = Orden::where('orden', $data['orden_id'])->firstOrFail();
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'El ID de orden proporcionado no existe en la tabla "ordenes"');
    }


     // Generar el ID aleatorio solo si no se proporcionó uno en el formulario
     $id = $request->input('RecepcionSuc');
     if (empty($id)) {
         do {
             $lastRecepcionSuc = RecepcionSuc::orderBy('RecepcionSuc', 'desc')->first();
             $lastNumber = $lastRecepcionSuc ? intval(substr($lastRecepcionSuc->RecepcionSuc, 1)) : 0;
             $id = 'S' . sprintf('%05d', $lastNumber + 1);
         } while (RecepcionSuc::where('RecepcionSuc', $id)->exists());
     }



    // Crear un nuevo registro en la tabla recepcion_suc y asignar los valores recibidos del formulario
    $recepcionSuc = new RecepcionSuc();
    $recepcionSuc->RecepcionSuc = $id;
    $recepcionSuc->orden_id = $data['orden_id'];
    $recepcionSuc->INE = $data['INE']->store('uploads'); // Almacena el archivo 'INE' en la carpeta 'storage/app/public/ine'
    $recepcionSuc->Copiafact = $data['Copiafact']->store('uploads'); // Almacena el archivo 'Copiafact' en la carpeta 'storage/app/public/copiafact'
    $recepcionSuc->poliza = $data['poliza']->store('uploads');
    $recepcionSuc->PersonaRecibio = $user->name;
    $recepcionSuc->observaciones = $data['observaciones'];
    $recepcionSuc->FechaIngTaller = $data['FechaIngTaller'];

    // Validación y procesamiento de otros campos del formulario
    // ...

    $recepcionSuc->save();

    return redirect()->route('ordenes.recepciona_suc.create')->with('success', 'Registrada correctamente');
}
```

Comment: Validar en tiempo real puede ser un problema. Para esto tienes que usar WebSockets, pero ¿se va a validar cada vez que se escriba un dígito en el `<input>`? Eso será un problema por ir será anti práctico porque no se podrá escribir bien. Además tienes que evaluar _pros y cons_, como la posibilidad de escalar el servidor y los precios por hacerlo. Sería mejor detectar cuando el usuario  deja de escribir y efectuar una petición HTTP?

Comment: Cuando se escriba la orden al final me valide si no existe me salga un mensaje que no existe.

Comment: Podrías utilizar [`livewire`](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation#real-time-validation) junto con `laravel`, tiene la opción de validar en tiempo real y también tiene la opción de validar cuando se oprima un botón para no validar cada vez que se ingresa un caracter en el `input`.

Comment: Por que dejar que el usuario escriba en un input tipo texto, si podrías poner un select con las opciones validas?

Comment: porque puede haber 5000 ids de ordenes